# [HTMLDivElement].appendChild([HTMLDivElement]) returning TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to append a div element to another div element with JS, but it throws an error:

```js
let SynthVoice = class {
  constructor(name){
    this.synthPanel = document.createElement("div");
    this.synthContainer = document.getElementById("synthChannels"); // div element
    this.synthPanel.id = name; // "synth0"
    this.synthContainer.appendChild(this.synthPanel);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/synth/overhaul.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/synth/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="createSynth" onclick="synth0 = new SynthVoice('synth0')">Create Synth 0</button>
    <div id="synthChannels"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
#synthChannels {
  display: flex;
}
```

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

All the code shown is in the constructor of the class `SynthVoice`, of which a new instance is created on the click of a button. Other answers on StackOverflow and MDN say this code should work, but it doesn't -- help!

Edit: Added some additional code so the error can (hopefully) be reproduced more easily

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/xuwelexega/1/edit?html,css,js,output). Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Added more code to hopefully make the issue reproducible

Comment: [I still cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/vinetitehi/1/edit?html,css,js,output). I had to remove the `let` otherwise the inline handler doesn't have access to `SynthVoice`

Comment: The only extra resource I can provide at this point is the entire glitch project: https://pseudoname.glitch.me/synth/main2.html  If my issue is that I'm using Glitch then I will have to come up with a workaround for now

Comment: The code that throws an error is ```document.getElementById(name).appendChild(`<select id="${name}shape" oninput="${name}.detectWaveShape()"></select><br /><br />`);``` on line 44 of [overhaul.js](https://pseudoname.glitch.me/synth/overhaul.js) - [screenshot of source](https://i.imgur.com/pV0itGt.png). It does not look like the code you've supplied in the question is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you, solved